# How does Spring recognize custom Cache Manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring allows custom cache if you create a class for cache manager.
How does that work under the hood? How does Spring recognize our custom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your cache manager as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class then spring does the rest (don't forget to also add `@EnableCaching` to your configuration class).

e.g.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager myCacheManager() {
    MyCacheManager cacheManager = new MyCacheManager();
    cacheManager.addCache(new MyCache("myCache"));
    cacheManager.addCache(new MyCache("myOtherCache"));
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Your cache manager class must implement spring's `CacheManager` interface.

Then to use it, `@Autowire` CacheManager myCacheManager into your component and use it like so:

```
myCacheManager.getCache("myCache");
```

NB: spring likes to match things up by name, so if you call yours something other than `myCacheManager` (which I hope you will), make sure you use that name when you auto-wire it as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to explain how Spring match our custom myCacheManager by name? I'm trying to find it in Spring Boot source code

Comment: I *think* (not 100% sure, this is how I would do it...) but Spring will 'discover' all the beans at startup (using annotation processing) then use that collection of beans to do the dependency injection. e.g. ah, there's a dependency called `myCacheManager` of type `CacheManager`, let me see... ah yes, I have a bean that matches. If there are multiple matches, spring fails to start and throws an appropriate error. This also explains why spring services take a little while longer to start. I believe one of the advances for spring native is to do the autowiring at compile time.